# What causes this distortion in my perspective projection at steep view angles?

Tags: opengl, camera, projection, perspective

For various reasons – partly educational, partly technical – I'm writing a 3D game engine from scratch, using OpenGL 3.0; aiming for Core Profile, eventually, so of course I'm using a custom matrix stack and shaders.  I've got nearly all of that working, but I'm getting  strange results and not sure where I'm making a mistake.

The problem:  using a perspective projection matrix (based on the formulas from the OpenGL 2.1 Reference), everything looks great… until I aim the camera up or down at a steep angle, when it gets horribly distorted, as shown in the screenshots below.

I've checked out the answers [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15383/opengl-camera-causes-spatial-distortion) (though the video is unavailable, so I'm not sure if it's the same sort of distortion), and double-checked my code against my [refer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/bottom.php)[ences](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToMatrix/).  So far as I can tell the math is correct and I don't see any glaring typos, but I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes can help me find the cause – thanks in advance.

#### Code

If there's anything else relevant you need to look at, just ask.

```
Vector3f Util::normalize(const Vector3f &v)
{
    float d = std::sqrt(dot(v, v));
    return d ? (v / d) : v;
}

Vector4f Util::buildQuaternion(const Angle &angle, const Vector3f &axis)
{
    Angle halfAngle = 0.5f * angle;
    float c = halfAngle.cos(), s = halfAngle.sin();
    return Vector4f(s * axis.x, s * axis.y, s * axis.z, c);
}

Vector3f Util::rotate(const Vector3f &p, const Vector4f &q)
{
    Vector4f r = qmul(qmul(q, Vector4f(p.x, p.y, p.z, 0.0f)), ~q);
    return Vector3f(r.x, r.y, r.z);
}

void Util::orbit(Vector3f &planet, const Vector3f &sun, const Vector3f &up, const Angle &yaw, const Angle &pitch)
{
    Vector3f f = planet - sun;
    Vector3f s = cross(up, f);
    Vector4f qx = buildQuaternion(pitch, normalize(s));
    Vector4f qy = buildQuaternion(yaw, normalize(up));
    Vector3f r = rotate(f, qmul(qx, qy));
    planet = r + sun;
}

Transform &Transform::makeRotate(const Vector4f &q)
{
    float xx = q.x * q.x;
    float xy = q.x * q.y;
    float xz = q.x * q.z;
    float xw = q.x * q.w;
    float yy = q.y * q.y;
    float yz = q.y * q.z;
    float yw = q.y * q.w;
    float zz = q.z * q.z;
    float zw = q.z * q.w;
    float ww = q.w * q.w;

    float *m = m_matrix;
    m[ 0] = 1-2*(yy+zz); m[ 4] =   2*(xy-zw); m[ 8] =   2*(xz+yw); m[12] = 0.0;
    m[ 1] =   2*(xy+zw); m[ 5] = 1-2*(xx+zz); m[ 9] =   2*(yz-xw); m[13] = 0.0;
    m[ 2] =   2*(xz-yw); m[ 6] =   2*(yz+xw); m[10] = 1-2*(xx+yy); m[14] = 0.0;
    m[ 3] = 0.0;         m[ 7] = 0.0;         m[11] = 0.0;         m[15] = 1.0;
    return *this;
}

Transform &Transform::makeRotate(const Angle &angle, const Vector3f &axis)
{
    return makeRotate(Util::buildQuaternion(angle, axis));
}

Transform &Transform::makePerspective(const Angle &fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar)
{
    float f = (fov * 0.5f).cot();
    float e = f / aspect;
    float g = (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar);
    float h = 2.0f * zFar * zNear / (zNear - zFar);

    float *m = m_matrix;
    m[ 0] =  e ; m[ 4] = 0.0; m[ 8] =  0.0; m[12] = 0.0;
    m[ 1] = 0.0; m[ 5] =  f ; m[ 9] =  0.0; m[13] = 0.0;
    m[ 2] = 0.0; m[ 6] = 0.0; m[10] =   g ; m[14] =  h ;
    m[ 3] = 0.0; m[ 7] = 0.0; m[11] = -1.0; m[15] = 0.0;
    return *this;
}

Transform &Transform::makeLookAt(const Vector3f &eye, const Vector3f &center, const Vector3f &up)
{
    Vector3f f = Util::normalize(center - eye);
    Vector3f u = Util::normalize(up);
    Vector3f s = cross(f, u);
    u = cross(Util::normalize(s), f);

    float *m = m_matrix;
    m[ 0] =  s.x; m[ 4] =  s.y; m[ 8] =  s.z; m[12] = 0.0;
    m[ 1] =  u.x; m[ 5] =  u.y; m[ 9] =  u.z; m[13] = 0.0;
    m[ 2] = -f.x; m[ 6] = -f.y; m[10] = -f.z; m[14] = 0.0;
    m[ 3] =  0.0; m[ 7] =  0.0; m[11] =  0.0; m[15] = 1.0;
    return translate(-eye);
}

void Camera::orbit3P(const Angle &yaw, const Angle &pitch)
{
    /// 3rd-person orbit - move camera around subject
    Util::orbit(m_eye, m_center, m_up, yaw, pitch);
    m_dirty = true;
}

void Camera::orbit1P(const Angle &yaw, const Angle &pitch)
{
    /// 1st-person orbit - change camera direction
    Util::orbit(m_center, m_eye, m_up, -yaw, pitch);
    m_dirty = true;
}
```

#### Screenshots

Horizontal - all is well
[image: Horizontal - all is well]

About 45° - distortion begins to appear
[image: About 45° - distortion begins to appear]

Almost 90° - what is this I don't even
[image: Almost 90° - what is this I don't even]

(The ortho overlay was to help visualize the camera eye and center locations.)

Comment: Well, it's hard to debug this code, the first thing I would check is the matrix multiplication order, it is very easy to miss this one. Check you multiplication order, I would also try to set identity matrices and debug the others.

Comment: Sure, it's some 10 kloc, but not all in one file.  I actually think it's rather well organized. :)  Anyway, currently I'm only *using* identity matrices, except for some that are part of the model data and known to be correct (it's from a published game that has no such issues), and the projection matrix.  I will check out the ordering, though.

Comment: OK, didn't find any problems with the multiplication order:  it's strictly hierarchical, resulting in `Camera*Scene*Actor*Model` (in fact Scene and Actor are always identity for now).  I did discover that tweaking the camera's up-vector changes where the distortion happens, so maybe it's not a problem with the projection, but in `makeLookAt` or `orbit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside makeLookAt contains your error:

```
Vector3f f = Util::normalize(center - eye);
Vector3f u = Util::normalize(up);
Vector3f s = cross(f, u);
u = cross(Util::normalize(s), f);
```

`s` is not normalized.

It should be:

```
Vector3f f = Util::normalize(center - eye);
Vector3f u = Util::normalize(up);
Vector3f s = Util::normalize(cross(f, u));
u = cross(s, f); // no norm needed because s,f both unit length and orthogonal
```

If `up` and `f` (forward) are perpendicular, then `s` is already (approximately) unit length. That is why it works for looking horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: Believe it or not, after comparing my version to the Mesa library, I came to the same conclusion and successfully tested it – just moments before finding your answer.  I had this system working in an older version of the engine that used `gluLookAt`, without the distortion, so I knew it had to be possible.  This was definitely the solution, thanks!